# An inequality in numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Which number is larger? $\underbrace{888\cdots8}_\text{19 digits}\times\underbrace{333\cdots3}_\text{68 digits}$ or $\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}\times\underbrace{666\cdots67}_\text{68 digits}$? Why? How much is it larger?

Answer (score 20):

Let those four numbers be $a,b,c,d$ respectively. Then $a=2c$ and $d=2b+1$. So $cd-ab=c$.

Answer (score 5):

note that $$\underbrace{888\cdots8}_\text{19 digits}=2*\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}$$
and $$2*\underbrace{333\cdots3}_\text{68 digits}=\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits}$$
further
$$\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits}+1=\underbrace{666\cdots7}_\text{68 digits}$$
Thus
$$\underbrace{888\cdots8}_\text{19 digits}*\underbrace{333\cdots3}_\text{68 digits}=\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}*2*\underbrace{333\cdots3}_\text{68 digits}=
\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}*\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits}$$
which is by $\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}$ smaller than
$$\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}*\underbrace{666\cdots7}_\text{68 digits}=\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}*\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits}+$\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}$$

Comment: $\underbrace{888\cdots8}_\text{19 digits}\not=2\times\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}$. Why did you write it???/

Comment: it most truly does. $4*2=8$, $44*2=88$, $444*2=888$ etc.

Comment: Excuse me. You are right.

Comment: No problem, looking at my solution i can tell that i shouldve represented those big numbers using letters for a more elegant and less confusing proof.

Comment: In your answer: How did you get the last equality?

Comment: $\underbrace{666\cdots7}_\text{68 digits}=\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits}+1$,thus $\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}*\underbrace{666\cdots7}_\text{68 digits}=\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}*(\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits}+1)=\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}*\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits}+\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}$

Comment: Very good. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have
$\underbrace{888\cdots8}_\text{19 digits}\times\underbrace{333\cdots3}_\text{68 digits} = 
8\cdot 3 \cdot (\underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{19 digits}\times \underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{68 digits}) = 
24 \cdot (\underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{19 digits}\times \underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{68 digits})$.
Similarly we get
$\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}\times\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits} =
4\cdot 6 \cdot (\underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{19 digits}\times \underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{68 digits}) =
24 \cdot (\underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{19 digits}\times \underbrace{111\cdots1}_\text{68 digits})$.
So these two numbers are equal.

It is clear that 
$$\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}\times\underbrace{666\cdots6}_\text{68 digits} \le \underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}\times\underbrace{666\cdots7}_\text{68 digits}.$$
Since the multiplier is increased by one, the difference is exactly $\underbrace{444\cdots4}_\text{19 digits}$.